# Retrofit2 and kotlin

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm try to combine Kotlin RxJava and retrofit2.

```
@GET("/xxxxxxxxxxxx/{id}.json")
fun getHotel(@Part("id") id : String) : Observable<Response<Hotel>>
```

When I try to call this method (getHotels()):

```
   var subscription = HotelsFactory.getHotelService((activity.applicationContext as App)
            .client)
        .getHotel(arguments.getInt("id").toString())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({response -> showHotels(response)}) 
         {throwable ->       throwable.printStackTrace()}
    mSubscription.add(subscription)
```

I take this one:

> @Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding.

Comment: you should use `@Path` instead of `@Part`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use the `@Part` annotation where you should be using the `@Path` annotation, just replace it and you should be all set.

`@Part`, as the error describes, should be used when submitting multipart form data not for modifying the URL.